# How to get the first value in Map when key as ID

Tags: map, before-trigger

I have written trigger in Before insert for opportunitylineitem, i am collecting all productids in Map, i want to take first id of Product2 in map, How?

```
list<product2> Products = new list<product2>();
Products = [Select id,PIM_Type__c from product2 where id IN:ProductIds and (PIM_Type__c='Cloud Flexibility Mode'or PIM_Type__c='Cloud Serenity Mode')];
Map<Id, product2> productMap = new Map<Id, product2>();
if(Products.size()>0){
    for(Opportunitylineitem opp : trigger.new){
        productMap.put(opp.product2id, null);
    }
}

productMap.putAll([Select id,PIM_Type__c from product2 where id =:productMap.keySet() and (PIM_Type__c='Cloud Flexibility Mode'or PIM_Type__c='Cloud Serenity Mode')]);
```

I want to take first value of Productmap, it have added morethan one
products,How? can anyone guide for taking first key value in map

i have tried this one:

```
Map<ID, product2> m = new Map<ID, product2>([Select id,PIM_Type__c from product2 where id =:productMap.keySet() and (PIM_Type__c='Cloud Flexibility Mode'or PIM_Type__c='Cloud Serenity Mode') Limit 1]);



for (ID idKey : m.keyset()) {

    product2 a = m.get(idKey);

    System.debug(a);
     tt = a.PIM_Type__c;
     system.debug('product2 is' +tt);
```

but not working

Comment: Maps are, by definition, unordered. There is no "first" item in a map, nor is there a "last" item in a map. What is your objective?

Comment: Suppose if i am inserting two products in opportunity line item?,if the pimtype for two different cloud products it have to throw error

Comment: I want to take first element of map  and compare with another products of PIM type

Comment: I have edited my question with tried code also @sfdcfox

Answer (score -2):

```
Map<ID, product2> m = new Map<ID, product2();
//m is a map containing Id and product
List <ID> ListID = new list<ID>();
for (ID idList: m.keyset())
{
    ListID.add(idList);
}
system.debug(ListID[0]);
```

Comment: The explanation is as important as the solution. Also, as sfdcfox mentions, maps (and sets) are unordered collections (there is no "first", "second", or "last"). Using a loop here is unnecessary (there is a list constructor that takes a set). While you can get the first element of the list, you really need to take care to define what "first" means. In OP's case, "get the first value" wouldn't really accomplish what they were trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will take care to explain my code next time. I am a beginner in SF dev, so trying to resolve existing questions to upskill myself.